# Error while running Export-UnicornConfiguration cmdlet in the Sitecore PowerShell script

Tags: powershell-extensions, unicorn

I am triggering an SPE script from the code. SPE script contains a few checks but finally has `Export-UnicornConfiguration $configurationName`.

The script runs without any errors when it is triggered through *Execute Script* inside CMS. The only issue is when it is triggered from the code. Am I missing anything while calling from the code?

Even from the code, all the other cmdlets like Get-Item and Get-UnicornConfiguration works fine. But below exception occurs with `Export-UnicornConfiguration.`

```
using (ScriptSession scriptSession = ScriptSessionManager.NewSession("Default", true))
{
   string script = scriptItem["Script"];
   scriptSession.SetVariable("ConfigurationName", _configurationName);
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(script))
        scriptSession.ExecuteScriptPart(script, true);
}
```

Unicorn configuration

```
<configuration name="xxxxxxx_Content">                  
      <dataProviderConfiguration enableTransparentSync="false" />
      <predicate>
        <include name="xxxx" database="master" path="/sitecore/content/xxxxxxx">              
        </include>
      </predicate>          
      <syncConfiguration updateLinkDatabase="false" updateSearchIndex="false" />
 </configuration>
```

ERROR: Current context is not a job (Sitecore.Jobs.AsyncUI.InvalidContextException)at Sitecore.Jobs.AsyncUI.JobContext.get_Job()

   at Sitecore.Jobs.AsyncUI.SendMessageMe
ssage..ctor(Message message, Boolean postBack)

   at Spe.Core.Host.ScriptingHostUserInterface.WriteProgress(Int64 sourceId, ProgressRecord record)

   at System.Management.Automation.Intern
al.Host.InternalHostUserInterface.WriteProgress(Int64 sourceId, ProgressRecord record)

   at Unicorn.PowerShell.PowershellProgressStatus.Report(Int32 percent)

   at Unicorn.SerializationHe
lper.ReserializeConfigurations(IConfiguration[] configurations, IProgressStatus progress, ILogger additionalLogger)
Export-UnicornConfiguration : Reserialize failed. Review preceding logs for details.
At line:1 char:1

- Export-UnicornConfiguration "xxxxxxx_Content"

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Export-UnicornConfiguration], InvalidOperationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Unicorn.PowerShell.ExportUnicornConfigurationCommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue while running the `Export-UnicornConfiguration` command through SPE Remoting.

It appears to be caused by the fact that Unicorn does not distinguish between Interactive and Non-Interactive sessions. The SPE Console and ISE have specific code implemented to signal when code related to the UI (like `Write-Progress`) is running in an Interactive mode.

At the moment there does not appear to be a convenient solution. A change would need to be made to the command to address this issue.

Comment: Thanks, Michael for the confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways how I would approach this:

### 1. Run scripts in "non-interactive" mode

The theory is that because you are running it remotely/via code some of the UI parts of the code might fail.

The trick I suggest you is to replace `Write-Progress` implementation so it won't do any server callbacks during execution.

Save it as `Write-ProgressWebAPI` script

```powershell
function Write-Progress {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        $Activity,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        $CurrentOperation,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        $Status,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        $PercentComplete,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [switch]$Completed
    )

    process {
        # do nothing
    }
}
```

and import

`Import-Function Write-ProgressWebAPI`

at the beginning of your script with unicorn cmdlet call.

### 2. Rewrite `ExportUnicornConfigurationCommand`

Alternatively if **1** won't help, you can use source code and implement your own version or at least debug it
[ExportUnicornConfigurationCommand](https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn/blob/master/src/Unicorn/PowerShell/ExportUnicornConfigurationCommand.cs)

Notice `PowershellProgressStatus` usage.

Comment: Thanks, Alan for the inputs, tried the first option but did not work, we are parking this implementation aside for now.